# Constructor without arguments doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I wonder why the constructor doesn't work/get called in the first case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Test{
public:
    Test(){ std::cout << "1\n"; };
    Test(int){ std::cout << "2\n"; };
};


int main()
{
    Test a(); // actually doesn't call the constructor
    Test b(1); // "2"
    std::cout << (typeid(b).name()) << std::endl; // "4Test"
    std::cout << (typeid(a).name()); // "F4TestvE"
    return 0;
}
```

I've also found that typenames of created variables are strange. Can anybody explain such a behavior?

---

I use mingw gcc 4.7.2 for Windows to compile my projects

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: `Test a();` is treated as a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Test a();
```

Oh, that's an instantiation of `a`, an object of type `Test`.

```
Test a();
```

Oh, that's a declaration for a function of no arguments that returns something of type `Test`.

Oh, wait...

If you instead construct a `new a()`, or use an (empty) initialisation list, this ambiguity is avoided.

See [Herb Sutter's excellent article](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) for more.

Comment: I like the way you answered.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`Test a();` is interpreted as a declaration of a function named `a` that takes no parameters and returns an object of type `Test`.

To create an object, remove the parentheses:

```
Test a;
```

Comment: I know, the question is about why Test a(); does not work. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @James A) No you don't, otherwise you wouldn't have asked. B) I just told you why.

Answer (score 1):

remove the parenthesis after Test a();
it should be like test a;
and it will automatically trigger the constructor with no arguments